# PyQt & matplotlib - save image and display dynamically

Tags: image, dynamic, matplotlib, plot, pyqt4

I have made a GUI that takes in some data , sends it to another function. Then that function plots a graph and saves it as a jpeg image. Now I'd like to display this image in the GUI window as a pixmap label dynamically. 
I wait for a push button to be clicked and then the function is called. But I want the labels to get the pixmaps immediately after the plot is done within the called function and execution is returned back.

```
class Example(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        btn = QtGui.QPushButton('button', self)
        btn.setToolTip('<b>calculate</b>')
        btn.resize(btn.sizeHint())
        btn.move(150, 500)

        btn.clicked.connect(self.call)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap('image.jpg')
        label = QtGui.QLabel(self)
        label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        label.move(440, 50)

    def call(self):

        #plotting is done here
        plt.clf()
        plt.plot(x_data, y_data)
        plt.ylabel('y')
        plt.xlabel('x')
        plt.savefig('image.jpg', format='jpg')


def main():

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: why don't you want to embed the graph directly?  I don't quite understand what you question is.

Comment: Also, don't mix `pyplot` with guis (unless you are explicitly using a non-interactive backend).  The main loops will conflict and cause you headaches.

Comment: ok even that would be fine. But how do I send the plotted image directly to be shown? As in , how do I embed it?

Comment: See examples here http://matplotlib.org/examples/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt4.html